# import file into SAS from DropBox

Tags: sas, dropbox

I have trouble with importing both excel and csv files into SAS.  It is stored on DropBox on a folder I have locally mapped.

I have tried with:

```
proc import datafile="C:\Users\Maria\Dropbox\Speciale\skriveri\DATA\sas\csv\prove.xls"
     out=data
     dbms=xls 
     replace;
run;
```

The message in the log is:

```
ERROR: Physical file does not exist,
       C:\Users\Maria\Dropbox\Speciale\skriveri\DATA\sas\csv\prove.xls.
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
```

I have also tried importing a csv file by replacing xls with csv.

I have checked the path - it's correct and the file names are prove.csv and prove.xls.

I have a 64 bit computer, and tested with SAS 9.3 and 9.2.

Comment: Are you definitely running the code locally, i.e. not remotely on a server?

Comment: I doubt if SAS is able to see the Dropbox folder. Try putting the file in " C:\Users\Maria\<here>" and see what happens.

Comment: I'm running SAS on the computer. I have tried with the path "C:\Users\Maria\Documents\prove.xls" and get the error ERROR: Physical file does not exist, C:\Users\Maria\Documents\prove.xls.
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: PROCEDURE IMPORT used (Total process time):

Comment: Now it works. Apparently it was the dropbox that made it fail. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I edited the question to more accurately and concisely reflect the specific issue, to make it more helpful in the future.   @user102890 Can you make your suggestion an actual answer please, and then user1626092 can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt if SAS is able to see the Dropbox folder. Try putting the file in " C:\Users\Maria\" and see what happens.